# Installing graphics tools in xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

When trying to install 'graphics tools' in xcode (Xcode -> open developer tool -> More developer tools, I get:

```
{"responseId":"ba7bd79e-487a-49b6-9bf1-f4085dc9e27e","resultCode":1003,"resultString":"request.uri.notfound","userString":"Invalid request, Service mapping to the requested URL is not available. ","creationTimestamp":"2016-07-14T05:58:55Z","userLocale":"en_US","requestUrl":"https://developer.apple.com:443/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode","httpCode":200,"suppressed":[]}
```

When trying to install from here (downloads): https://developer.apple.com/opengl/

I get:

```
{"responseId":"76bb89d6-d9a7-4c67-b24e-d65c03e83973","resultCode":1003,"resultString":"request.uri.notfound","userString":"Invalid request, Service mapping to the requested URL is not available. ","creationTimestamp":"2016-07-14T06:00:40Z","userLocale":"en_US","requestUrl":"https://developer.apple.com:443/downloads/index.action?q=graphics","httpCode":200,"suppressed":[]}
```

Anyone got a idea how to install graphics tools?

/A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Search for: graphics

And select only the 'Developer tools' checkbox.

The confusion is total.

Comment: Worth a note that the latest tools say they're for Xcode 7.2, but they apparently work fine on my machine which has Xcode 8.1, and runs El Cap.

Answer (score 3):

Still confusing. As of 10.12 Sierra:

You can find the Graphic Tools in: "Aditional Tools for XCode":

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode
[image]

Comment: And does the OpenGL profiler works in your case ? Status keeps on "Waiting for profiling to start..." in my case, the app run but I cannot put breakpoints or suspend to look at resources. See a known issue wit XCode 8: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/204679